# Error when trying to use Contain in my SharePoint app (add-in)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run the following block of code.

error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error CS1929  'FieldCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'Contains' and the best extension method overload
>   'ParallelEnumerable.Contains(ParallelQuery, string)'
>   requires a receiver of type
>   'ParallelQuery'   OneDriveRetrival    C:\FTG\Projects\OneDriveRetrival\OneDriveRetrival\OneDriveOperations\OneDriveOps.cs 86

Code:

```
 string SharedWithFieldDefXml = "< Field ID = '{ef991a83-108d-4407-8ee5-ccc0c3d836b9}’ Type=’UserMulti’ DisplayName=’Shared With’ Mult=’TRUE’ Name=’SharedWithUsers’ StaticName=’SharedWithUsers’ Group=’_Hidden’ Sealed=’TRUE’ AllowDeletion=’FALSE’ ReadOnly=’TRUE’ ShowInDisplayForm=’FALSE’ ShowInEditForm=’FALSE’ ShowInListSettings=’FALSE’ Viewable=’FALSE’ SourceID='{ 86ea65fd - 7aea - 4dd1 - afdb - bbbce3c16daa}’ />";

            if (web.AvailableFields.Contains(SharedWithFieldDefXml) == false)
            {

                web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(MyFieldDefXml);

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing the `SPFieldCollection` object (server side) with the `FieldCollection` object (client side).

`SPFieldCollection` does have a `Contains` method, but as the error you are receiving points out, `FieldCollection` does not.

Here are links to the MSDN documentation:

[`SPFieldCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection_members.aspx)

[`FieldCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldcollection_members.aspx)

Comment: Thank for the info

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks like server object model code and this is not csom code at all which will only be compatible with your online site.

this is how you can create a new column using csom.

```
string SharedWithFieldDefXml = "<Field ID ='{ef991a83-108d-4407-8ee5-ccc0c3d836b9}’ Type=’UserMulti’ DisplayName=’Shared With’ Mult=’TRUE’ Name=’SharedWithUsers’ StaticName=’SharedWithUsers’ Group=’_Hidden’ Sealed=’TRUE’ AllowDeletion=’FALSE’ ReadOnly=’TRUE’ ShowInDisplayForm=’FALSE’ ShowInEditForm=’FALSE’ ShowInListSettings=’FALSE’ Viewable=’FALSE’ SourceID='{ 86ea65fd - 7aea - 4dd1 - afdb - bbbce3c16daa}’ />";

FieldCollection fields = web.AvailableFields;
IEnumerable<Field> filteredFields = context.LoadQuery(fields.Where(f => f.InternalName == "FieldName"));
   context.ExecuteQuery();

   SP.Field newField = filteredFields.FirstOrDefault();
   if (newField == null)
   {
   newField = CurrentList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(SharedWithFieldDefXml, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldToDefaultView);
   web.Fields.Add(newField);
   context.Load(newField);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   }
```

For more information see this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b84cf90-22a8-40b2-ac8d-86f1a652dfce/add-a-field-to-site-columns-using-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious).